# Issue Google+ Signin on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-signin

I'm experiencing a curious issue with Google+ Signin. I am using the code very closely to what they post on their Developer site.

**My Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auth2;


var initClient = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'MYCLIENTIDHERE.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile'
        });

        jQuery('#signin-button').unbind();
        auth2.attachClickHandler('signin-button', {}, onSuccess, onFailure);
    });
};


var onSuccess = function(user) {
    console.log('Signed in as ' + user.getBasicProfile().getName());

    do_all_my_other_stuff_not_important_for_here();
};

var onFailure = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};
</script>
```

**Behavior**

When clicking the `#singin-button` in Chrome, most of the time NOTHING seems to happen. If in another browser, like Firefox, it works as expected.

I am pretty sure there is nothing else in my code screwing this up since when I run the identical source code on my local machine, it also works as expected (regardless of the Browser).

**Question**

I am really at a loss as to where to even begin to diagnose this problem any further. What would you do? Thoughts on where to look for possible solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have been grappling with this issue for months off and on. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

When I get frustrated with something, eventually I just throw a `console.log` everywhere I can think and just see what fires and when.

Low and behold, I found out that `initClient` was not being triggered. Hmm....

Something was wrong with the `onload` parameter of the Google API.

My code was like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=initClient" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var auth2;

var initClient = function() {
    ...
```

Perhaps initClient was not being created when the api was ready to fire it. So I swapped positions. I put the call to the API ***after*** the declaration. Low and behold, it worked!

After months, it just so happens the day I try and solicit some thoughts from others I finally figured it out.

Ugh. I cannot believe I did not figure that out sooner.